# Not able to send post data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

My code looks like this

```
var data = new FormData();
        var ids = file[f].name._unique();
        data.append('file',file[f]);
        data.append('index',ids);
        data = data  + "&moredata=morevalue" ; //when I am uncommenting this line everything is working 
        $(".dfiles[rel='"+ids+"']").find(".progress").show();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:this.config.uploadUrl,
            data:data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(rponse){
                $("#"+ids).hide();
                var obj = $(".dfiles").get();
                $.each(obj,function(k,fle){
                    if($(fle).attr("rel") == rponse){
                        $(fle).slideUp("normal", function(){ $(this).remove(); });
                    }
                });
                if (f+1 < file.length) {
                    self._uploader(file,f+1);
                }
            }
        });
    } else
        console.log("Invalid file format - "+file[f].name);
}
```

I want to add  key and values to the POST array **moredata and morevalue** you can see this in 5th line,when I am uncommenting that line I am able to send the data via post but I am not getting why my code is not working by adding moredata and morevalue:

```
data = data  + "&moredata=morevalue" ;
```

Here is the project folder for reference:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4fc78os0j0t9b8j/kayiL1DkgI/arulsir

Comment: Do you mean when commenting(with `//`) the code is working and when uncommenting(without `//`) code is not working?

Comment: `if () {`? Really? Either you've got a syntax error right there or you've oversimplified. If the `if` isn't relevant to your question don't include it at all.

Comment: @JohnBlake I mean commenting the whole line .When I am commenting the whole line it is working.I mean When I dont add moredata and morevalue to the data

Comment: @nnnnnn I shown you part of the code.There is no syntax errror.I believe this is something related to the http data type

Comment: My apologies, I now realise that the bit I was complaining about was introduced by another person's edit. I've rolled it back to your original version (which still has an extra `} else ...` at the end, but at least that isn't as misleading as the edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the last line in the question I assume, it is not working when you uncomment the line `data = data + "&moredata=morevalue";`

So you need to add additional data to `data` using

```
data.append('moredata', 'morevalue');
```

Comment: the post data is going.But the images are not being uploaded.

Comment: here is the project folder https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4fc78os0j0t9b8j/kayiL1DkgI/arulsir